# Create issue over github using java

Tags: java, github, egit, issue-tracking

I want to create issue over GitHub using java EGIT API.

I have tried it:

```
GitHubClient client = new GitHubClient().setCredentials("abc", "xyz");

IssueService service = new IssueService(client);

Repository repo = new Repository();
```

Comment: I think this feature would be incredibly useful for error reporting in applications. Too bad you need an account to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve this using [EGit 2.1.5](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.mylyn.github/org.eclipse.egit.github.core/2.1.5). Here are the steps I took:

1. I created a Personal Access Token in the project `https://github.com/settings/tokens`. When creating the Token, specify the `scope` to your needs. For my case (just Issue creation), I opted for `repo scope`. [image]

Sweet, now that we have our `token` let's jump into the code.

```
GitHubClient client = new GitHubClient();
client.setOAuth2Token("PUT_YOUR_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE"); // Use the token generated above
IssueService issueService = new IssueService(client);
try {
    Issue issue = new Issue();
    issue.setTitle("Test issue"); // Title of the issue
    issue.setBody("Some stuff"); // Body of the issue
    // Other stuff can be included in the Issue as you'd expect .. like labels, authors, dates, etc. 
    // Check out the API per your needs
    
    // In my case, we utilize a private issue-only-repository "RepositoryIssueTracker" that is maintainted under our Organization "MyCompany"
    issueService.createIssue("MyCompany", "RepositoryIssueTracker", issue);
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Failed");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Summary:**
I think OP's issue was related to not providing proper credentials, possibly to a private repo. I also was unable to get `Basic` auth working with a username/password to our private repo (possibly because our organization requires 2-factor). Instead, using a `Personal Access Token` Authorization worked per the above instructions.

More info on creating an issue-only repository can be found [here](https://docs.github.com/en/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/creating-a-repository-on-github/creating-an-issues-only-repository).